# PHPmailer Fatal Error

Tags: php, mailer

Hi guys i'm trying to use a php mailer however I keep getting issues for example in the sampler my emails simply won't send. So I changed to this new method and when testing i'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home3/hutch/public_html/Murphy/class.phpmailer.php on line 1325` anyone know why this is. I tried chanign the require to `("PHPMailerAutoload.php");` Which still didn't work still got the same error. I got both class.phpmailer.php and PHPMailerAutoload.php from the Github hosted documentation so I'm sure they are up to date. Any ideas?

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.sulmaxmarketing.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "info@sulmaxmarketing.com";
$mail->AddAddress("sulmaxcp@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 

else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending email using SMTP, so you need to include the SMTP class file:

```
require("class.smtp.php");
```

Comment: Worked a dream thank you, quick question when the email came through it said the name was from Root User how do I change this?

Comment: @MattHutch You can use `$mail->FromName = "My Name";`